# Haskell iterate through each 2x2 grid over a list of list and apply function

Tags: list, haskell

suppose I have a list of list `xs`. Each element in `xs` has the same length (e.g. `xs` is not like `[[1,2],[1],[1,2,3]]`). And I have a function `f`, which return a `Bool`. I want to apply `f` to each of the 2x2 grid in `xs` and get the ***AND*** result of the applications.

For example,

```
xs = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

f :: [[Int]] -> Bool
f [[1,_][_,_]] = False
f _ = True ​
```

In this case, I want to

- apply `f` to `[[1,2],[4,5]]` and return `False`
- apply `f` to `[[2,3],[5,6]]` and return `True`
- apply `f` to `[[4,5],[7,8]]` and return `True`
- apply `f` to `[[5,6],[8,9]]` and return `True`

Then the final result should be `False` as 3 Trues and 1 False result in False.

Currently I write a function that help me to extract a 2x2 grid from the list

```
get_grid :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
get_grid xs = map (take 2) (take 2 xs)
```

Is there any way to iterate over `xs` by `get_grid` and apply `f` in each iteration and **AND** the result?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Shouldn't the signature be `get_grid :: [[Int]] -> [[[Int]]]` since there are a *list* of grids.

Comment: Nah this function extracts only one grid each time. So it is just ```[[Int]]```, not a list of grids.

Comment: @AhSoHard, honestly I don't see the pattern. I think you should clarify a bit. For instance, why isn't `[[1,3],[4,6]]` a possible input to `f`? "2x2 grid in `xs`" is of zero help in understanding what you mean.

Comment: @Enlico it's 2x2 cells in a 2D grid/matrix.

Comment: @WillNess, hence I asked what about `[[1,3],[4,6]]`. I don't know what a "cell in 2D grid/matrix" is. As regards matrices, submatrices need not be made up of contiguous sub-columns/sub-rows. The question is simply poorly written, based on the assumption that the reader is sitting beside the OP and seeing what he/she does.

Comment: @Enlico, so think ```xs``` as a chessboard. You can think a 2x2 cell/grid as a 2x2 square formed up by 4 single/atom square. So in this case, ```[[1,3], [4,6]]``` cannot form up a 2x2 square, it can only form up two 1x2 rectangles. Thus ```[[1,3], [4,6]]``` is not a valid case. Sorry for any confusion caused to you.

Comment: @AhSoHard, no worries. It seems you accepted the answer, so reading that I'll understand what the question means, probably :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write a function to get all adjacent pairs from a list:

```
pairs :: [a] -> [[a]]
pairs (x:y:rest) = [x,y] : pairs (y:rest)
pairs _ = []
```

you can apply it to your matrix to get the submatrices consistent of adjacent pairs of rows:

```
> pairs xs
[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]]
```

Transpose each of these submatrices:

```
> map transpose . pairs $ xs
[[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]],[[4,7],[5,8],[6,9]]]
```

and then split them into submatrices of pairs of rows, as before:

```
> concatMap pairs . map transpose . pairs $ xs
[[[1,4],[2,5]],[[2,5],[3,6]],[[4,7],[5,8]],[[5,8],[6,9]]]
```

and transpose them back:

```
> map transpose . concatMap pairs . map transpose . pairs $ xs
[[[1,2],[4,5]],[[2,3],[5,6]],[[4,5],[7,8]],[[5,6],[8,9]]]
```

Those are the matrices you wanted, and you can check that `f` is true for all of them with:

```
> all f . map transpose . concatMap pairs . map transpose . pairs $ xs
False
```

A full example:

```
import Data.List

pairs :: [a] -> [[a]]
pairs (x:y:rest) = [x,y] : pairs (y:rest)
pairs _ = []

f :: [[Integer]] -> Bool
f [[1,_],[_,_]] = False
f _ = True

xs :: [[Integer]]
xs = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

ys :: [[Integer]]
ys = [[0,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

check_grid :: ([[a]] -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> Bool
check_grid f = all f . map transpose . concatMap pairs . map transpose . pairs

main = do
  print $ check_grid f xs
  print $ check_grid f ys
```